# Cronjob to check if service is running, if not starting service

Tags: curl, cron

I need a cronjob, that check if a page is running.
I think by check if the HTTP response status code is "200".

If the status code is not "200" a bash code must be executed.

I hope someone can help me with this topic. I tried it by myself but I have no idea how to get the code working.

Comment: Which page is running?

Comment: the Cron job could run a php script which makes a curl request and checks the response code. If you tried something, please show your code and explain the specific issue you encountered

Answer (score 2):

You can use it like..

```
#!/bin/bash

status_code=$(curl --write-out %{http_code} --silent --output /dev/null https://www.my-site.com/)

if [[ "$status_code" -ne 200 ]] ; then
    ## do your stuff here
  echo "Site status changed to $status_code"
else
  exit 0
fi
```

Comment: this worked local for me but on the server it dosent worked

Comment: @hendrik this is a bash script which should be executed at you set interval.